# Is there any significance of not having haircuts on Tuesdays and Fullmoon day?

Tags: belief, practice, superstitions

It is enforced at my place and many of Brahmins community to not have haircuts on Tuesday, Full Moon Day, `Birth days`

May i know the reason for the same if there is any significant aspect behind these custom?

Comment: I read somewhere that earlier people used to take haircut on Mondays so on Tuesday, there was pretty much no one who would want a haircut so it was considered a off day and that same practice is continued till day.